# creating an object of a class to test a method python

Tags: python, object

From a question in Leetcode, solution is correct but wanted to test it myself in VSCode by creating an instance and then printing the result of the method twoSum. Not sure how to though.

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        count1 = 0
        for i in nums:
            count2 = 0
            for j in nums:
                if (i+j) == target and i != j:
                    return count1, count2
                count2 +=1
                
            count1 +=1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(twoSum([2,7,11,15],9 ))
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You first have to instantiate a `Solution` instance by doing -

```
s=Solution()
```

And then call the method -

```
s.twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9)
```